# Asp.net textbox in Android phone with numeric keyboard selected by default

Tags: android, keyboard, numeric

We are developing a regular asp.net website (no Textviews), for one of the text boxes I need the textbox to open a numeric keyboard by default, is there a way to achieve this?

Below code works perfectly for iPhone / iPad but does not default to numeric keyboard for Android.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="number" pattern="\d*" onKeypress="if(event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57){return false;}" />
```

Adroid version : 2.2.1

EDIT :
When I use an HTML input box with type="number" it works perfectly. I need a way to use asp.Net textbox and see the numeric keyboard.

Comment: type="number" is supposed to work: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#form-types-mobile

Comment: It did work but not with <asp:TextBox> rather I had to convert that to an HTML input box, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
<div style="display:none"><asp:TextBox ID="txt_Phone" runat="server" /></div>
<input onblur="document.getElementById('<%=txt_Phone.ClientID %>').value = this.value" type="tel" />
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more elegant way:

```
PhoneBox.Attributes.Add("type", "tel");
```

This way there is only one input control and it doesn't mess up client-side validation. Also it makes it easy to assign this attribute to multiple controls (I just added a "keypad" class to the controls that I want it to apply to, then use a recursive control search method to find them all and add the attribute).