# TextBox Type="tel" dont save value in TextBoxName.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

When I use `type="text"` it's working. When I changed to `type="tel"` and when I wrote some chars in this textbox everytime i have `TextBoxName.Text=""`. (I need this type only for keyboard style in mobile devices if you know any other example how can I do this I will be glad)

- Web forms asp.net 4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp.net textbox in Android phone with numeric keyboard selected by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765990/asp-net-textbox-in-android-phone-with-numeric-keyboard-selected-by-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing like `type="tel"`, so if you want to make it number, then you need to do like this :

```
type="number"
```

Comment: I need other type of keyboard than number i need special chars like / - ; : And I cant use that chars in `type="number"`

Comment: so you want to key something like `1223#8$5`?

Comment: exactly. I need something like `123543/2`

Comment: But I need to display on mobile devices keyboard like default keyboard in `type="tel"`